# Build Swift Package Library and an iOS project at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, build, swift-package-manager

I want to create an iOS project and Swift Library in the same workspace. Everything is working fine, the only problem is that I have to build the library first if I want to add something new.

Is there a way to build both at the same time or in order with a single button?

[image]